# Sistema de Agendamento por Data

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tenho um sistema de agendamento, onde tenho que retornar as datas e horários disponíveis *(que não esteja cadastradas no banco obviamente)* para um novo agendamento com essas datas e horários disponíveis. Não tenho uma noção de como fazer isto, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Estou usando PHP + MySQL.
    [image: Algo como esta imagem!]

Comment: O que você já tentou?  Como é o esquema da sua tabela? O agendamento é de hora em hora?

Comment: @acklay ainda não imaginei nada quanto ao banco. Más seria um horário intercalado, podendo ser de 1hora há 2horas

Comment: Nunks você pode me ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369467/data-e-hor%C3%A1rio-para-atendimento-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment736463_369467

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na falta de um gerador de série de data/timestamp (não consegui encontrar essa funcionalidade na documentação do MySQL), eu criaria uma tabela com o range de horários possíveis (das 9h às 17h, por exemplo), uma com datas e horários cadastrados, e cruzaria uma com a outra para obter os horários disponíveis.

**Edit: a resposta original não suportava múltiplas datas**

(*O princípio da coisa é o mesmo, só mudei as consultas para incluir dinamicamente em horarios_possiveis a data de agendamento a ser verificada*)

```
create table horarios_possiveis (horario time not null unique);
insert into horarios_possiveis (horario) values 
('09:00'),('10:00'),('11:00'),('12:00'),
('13:00'),('14:00'),('15:00'),('16:00'),
('17:00');

create table horarios_cadastrados (data date not null, horario time not null, constraint unique agendamento (data, horario));
insert into horarios_cadastrados (data, horario) values 
('2017-09-15', '10:00'),('2017-09-15', '12:00'),
('2017-09-15', '13:00'),('2017-09-15', '15:00'),
('2017-09-16', '09:00'),('2017-09-16', '15:00');

select * from horarios_possiveis;

select * from horarios_cadastrados;

select p.* from (select '2017-09-15' data, horario from horarios_possiveis) p
left join horarios_cadastrados c on p.horario=c.horario and p.data=c.data
where c.data is null;

select p.* from (select '2017-09-16' data, horario from horarios_possiveis) p
left join horarios_cadastrados c on p.horario=c.horario and p.data=c.data
where c.data is null;
```

Resultado:

```
| horarios_possiveis |
|  horario           |
|--------------------|
| 09:00:00           |
| 10:00:00           |
| 11:00:00           |
| 12:00:00           |
| 13:00:00           |
| 14:00:00           |
| 15:00:00           |
| 16:00:00           |
| 17:00:00           |

|  horarios_cadastrados |
|       data |  horario |
|------------|----------|
| 2017-09-15 | 10:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 12:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 13:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 15:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 09:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 15:00:00 |

| horarios_livres_09-15 |
|       data |  horario |
|------------|----------|
| 2017-09-15 | 09:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 11:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 14:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 16:00:00 |
| 2017-09-15 | 17:00:00 |

| horarios_livres_09-16 |
|       data |  horario |
|------------|----------|
| 2017-09-16 | 10:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 11:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 12:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 13:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 14:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 16:00:00 |
| 2017-09-16 | 17:00:00 |
```

[Exemplo no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44cc9/28)